# Problem with function as an argument

Tags: programming, functions

I want to write a function like the following:

```
s[u_, v_, x_, val_] := u[val]/NIntegrate[u'[x] v[x] + u'[x] v'[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

So I can evaluate something like

```
s[Cos[x], Sin[3 x], x, 5]
```

I have a strong feeling that my approach is incorrect, however, I couldn't find the right one.

**Update:**

Thanks to b.gatessucks, who wrote the correct version of what I was trying to achieve. However, after that I tried to use that approach on lists:

```
r = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
u[x_, i_] := Sin[r[[i]] x];
A = Table[s[u[#, i] &, u[#, j] &, 5], {i, 5}, {j, 5}]
```

After this, I get a matrix, but I also get a bunch of errors, so I don't know if I can trust the output. The errors are:

```
Part::pspec: Part specification #2 is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
Part::pspec: Part specification #2 is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
Part::pspec: Part specification #2 is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
General::stop: "Further output of Part::pspec: will be suppressed during this calculation."
```

Comment: You have an extra `_` in the right-hand side. Next, you can drop the `x` argument and evaluate you function as `s[Cos[#] &, Sin[3 #] &, 5]`.

Comment: It actually worked, thanks! However, would be nice to find some guide on operators as such, google is not very helpful with those symbols.

Comment: "some guide on operators" - see [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PureFunctions.html), for starters...

Comment: and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/134) thread full of useful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite some practice with *Mathematica*, I still consider myself a newbie. However, I have come to understand that a *function* and an *expression* are two different things, despite the fact that the documentation seems to use them indistinctly (if I am wrong, glad to hear the comment of an expert!)

So, what I did and that seems to work with **s** is to consider **u** and **v** as *expression* parameters - therefore the use of `/.` inside, with the *symbol* parameter **x** - and define the *functions* inside, so as to apply `'` later on. The code is:

```
s[u_, v_, x_, val_] := Module[{f, g},
   f[t_] := u /. x -> t;
   g[t_] := v /. x -> t; 
   f[val]/NIntegrate[f'[t] g[t] + f'[t] g'[t], {t, 0, 1}]
   ];
```

which gives the output

> In[9]:= s[Cos[x], Sin[3 x], x, 5]
>
> Out[9]= 2.36249

Hope helps.

(By the way: I believe it is in these cases that you want to use HoldFirst, HoldAll and related evaluation attributes.)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!